# launching Excel application using Python to view the CSV file , but CSV file is opening in read mode and cant view the data written on it

Tags: python, excel, csv

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
base_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))        
_csvFilename = os.path.join(base_path, "bcForecasting.csv")
_csvFile = open (_csvFilename, 'wb')
_csvFile = csv.writer(_csvFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

_Header = ['Name']+self.makeIntoList (self.root.tss.series () [0].getAllTimes (), self.originalTimesteps + _futurePeriods)
_csvFile.writerow (_Header)

xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(_csvFilename)  
xl.Visible = True
```

Here launching  Excel application using Python to view the CSV file , but CSV file is opening in read mode and cant view the data written on it. Please help.

Comment: Did you try closing the file first? Windows doesn't like it when more than one application has a file opened.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters  thanks it works. It was due to not closing the file . Now i closed the file and then opened the file, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You need to *close* the `csv` file before you open it with Excel:

```
with open (_csvFilename, 'wb') as _csvFile
    _csvFile = csv.writer(_csvFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    _Header = ['Name']+self.makeIntoList (self.root.tss.series () [0].getAllTimes (), self.originalTimesteps + _futurePeriods)
    _csvFile.writerow (_Header)

xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(_csvFilename)  
xl.Visible = True
```

By using a `with` statement the open file object is automatically closed when the block indented under the statement completes.

Windows doesn't like it when more than one application has a file open.